# Calling JSNI method from Java method

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have following code:

```java
public static void show(String value){
   Window.alert("From Java");
   invokeMethod(); //Does not get called
}  

public static native void invokeMethod() /*-{ 
    alert("From JSNI");
}-*/;
```

I want to call a JSNI method from Java method, however `invokeMethod()` never gets called...
I could not find much use cases for calling JSNI method from Java.

Why isn't above code working?

Comment: your code should work. Something else going wrong outside this code maybe?

Comment: change the jsni to use `$wnd.alert` instead of `alert`. And make sure to click 'ok' on the first alert, or the second alert can't run.

Comment: "And make sure to click 'ok' on the first alert, or the second alert can't run." this doesn't matter since a alert, both alerts will get triggerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Colin Alworth said, you need to change your code to $wnd.alert("From JSNI"); If you want to call another JS function apart from alert(), you should write the body of your function in your html page. You'll find all information needed [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#calling)

So your code should look like this:

```java
public static void show(String value){
   Window.alert("From Java");
   invokeMethod(); 
}  

public static native void invokeMethod() /*-{ 
    $wnd.alert("From JSNI"); //Added "$wnd."
}-*/;
```